# ubuntu 16.04 touchpad not working

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, lenovo, elantech

I have a lenovo ideapad 320. After installing ubuntu 16.04, the touchpad hasn't been working.

sometimes the touchpad will work for a few minutes after restarting, but it eventually stops working again. the touchpad is enabled in settings, and a usb mouse works just fine.

from xinput:

Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]

⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]

what should I do to fix this?